# ASP.NET webservice: one call to my XmlHttp results in a double'd request

Tags: asp.net, web-services, request, xmlhttprequest

i have a very strange problem with my webservice:

- its a typical/standard ASP.NET (v4) webservice, beeing called via GET.
- everything works fine, but today i did a trace since i set up a customn http-module
- in this http-module i put some logging-calls, in begin/end-request
- when viewing the logs, i can see that if my service get called once (by the clients JS-method), actually two request are done to the webservice

(the http-module runs also for standard ASP.NET winform pages, there i do not have this issue - it occurs only in case of calling the webservice)

Does anybody has an idea what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A redirect might cause this behavior, e.g. to add a slash to the end of a slashless URL. Also, many authentication schemes may require two requests. If I were in your shoes, I'd look at both requests' content and headers to see what's inside.

Also, you might want to run Fiddler (or any other network tracer, like Firebug or IE dev toolbar) on the client to verify that the client is actually making two requests. It could be that where you have your logging code in the HttpModule might be in a place where multiple calls is natural (e.g. once for headers, once for body).

Comment: Hi Justin, with an additonal slash at the end the request looks like `http://localhost/XRSF.asmx/RMG?Param1=0&Param2=0/` - making the service crash... Fiddler, OK - i will try that as next option!

Comment: OK, as suggested by you, i tried Fiddler - and in fact, it shows only one request per webservice call... strange, so it must be in the http-module -> How can i find out more about your second tip, regarding places where multiple runs through the http-module are natural? i'm doing the http-module loggin stuff in `PreRequestHandlerExecute` and in `PostRequestHandlerExecute` - and: it seems both requests are cascaded, since i have two calls to `Pre...Execute` following each other before first call to `Post...Execute` is called. Any other idea? Thx

Comment: OK, some further investigation shows, it seems to be something with the keep-alive-stuff in the requests call.

Comment: Still no luck, i found some threads on the net, some people experiencing same problem; the double-invokation of `code`PreReq...`code` also occurs for the initial call to WebResource.axd

Comment: Another thing i found out is: when the first call happens, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null/not available, but for the second call Session-state is available.

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
this is not the final solution but a good work around:

the problem is:

- in case of a clients JS-call to the webservice module, the functions are executed twice since the module is run two times: one for CurrentHandler==TransferRequestHandler, the second call (in which session-state is available) then is processed by CurrentHandler==Script/ASPX/Handler
- i do not know (until now) whats the reason but i solved it simply by returning/not executing my HttpModule-specific stuff on the first run
- so, it works OK but i'm still looking for an explanation, why the HttpModule PreExecute/PostExecuteRequestHandler is called twice in case of a WebService-call, while it is *not* called twice for a single/standard ASP.NET page request

Regards